# Time Job Cannot Pass Proxy Server

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, web-config

I am just wondering how SharePoint Timer Job works with external services. 
We have a web part and timer job that both call external service. Web part didn't pass our proxy as well, but after we changed proxy setting in web.config of that web application it works now.

How can we set our Timer Job to pass the proxy? It seems that is not related directly to our web application where we have installed our web part.

Answer (score 0):

Read the same web.config with this code:

```
SPWebApplication webApp = this.Parent as SPWebApplication;  
Configuration config = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("/", webApp.Name);  
String appValue = config.AppSettings.Settings["appSettingKey"].Value;
```